What is the mathematical convention of MLKit's Euler Angles?
I'm working on a Google MLKit application where I would like to calculate the detected face's coordinate system. From the face's perspective, the x-axis would go right, the y-axis would go down, and the z-axis would go out the front (this seems to align with Google's convention described below).
MLKit returns three Euler Angles, which in theory should be enough to determine the three axis directions. For instance to get the direction of the face's x-axis, one could start with a unit vector pointing in the camera-aligned x-direction x_hat = (1,0,0), then multiply the vector through three rotation matrices, one for each Euler angle. This can then be repeated for y_hat and z_hat.
However, one problem is that the Euler angle rotation matrices are non-commutative, meaning that the result depends on the order the rotations are applied in. I was reading Google's MLKit Documentation and it wasn't clear to me what the ordering convention would be. This is basically all Google has to say about the returned Euler Angles:

Face orientation
The following terms describe the angle a face is oriented with respect to the camera:

Euler X: A face with a positive Euler X angle is facing upward.
Euler Y: A face with a positive Euler Y angle is looking to the right of the camera, or looking to the left if negative.
Euler Z: A face with a positive Euler Z angle is rotated counter-clockwise relative to the camera.


According to Wikipedia a common convention is 1. yaw 2. pitch 3. roll, which in Google's convention I believe would be YXZ (extrinsic). But since Google's documentation doesn't explicitly say what the convention is, it's probably not safe to assume this.
Is there anyone more familiar with the Google MLKit library that knows Google's ordering convention, if one wanted to combine them in order to calculate the correct final face orientation?
